# Pedal Stroke Analysis on a BikeErg

Tags: pedals, technique

Hello I'm in the market for an indoor bike and am considering the BikeErg. I'd like to know if there is a way I can do pedal stroke analysis like that offered by the Wattbike (https://support.wattbike.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115001848609-A-Beginner-s-Guide-To-Perfect-Pedalling) and the Elite (https://elitesrl.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014522080-Pedalling-Analysis).

It's ok if the BikeErg itself doesn't have these capabilities. For example, I'm also open to a solution which involves using special pedals/sensors clipped to my shoes, or pedals with inbuilt power meters, etc.

Comment: Which BikeErg documentation did you read? Also, both of your links are broken.

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed the links.

Comment: Just use rollers.  The feedback is much faster:  if your pedal stroke isn't smooth you'll fall over.  :-)